# 18.04: Can't install docker in offline mode using snap

Tags: snap, docker, ubuntu-core, multipass

How do I install docker using snap without an internet connection.

I have installed Ubuntu using [Multipass](https://multipass.run/). My OS details:

```
root@docker:/home/ubuntu/microk8s# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: docker
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 623942f2a0ca411a85486e31ec4949e7
           Boot ID: 429b1a83e1b8418496bcfde7e435ab61
    Virtualization: bhyve
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-76-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I have the docker snaps offline.

```
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# ls
docker_423.assert  docker_423.snap
```

On trying to install it offline, I get

```
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# snap ack docker_423.assert
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# snap install docker_423.snap
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Ensure prerequisites for "docker" are available (Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers))
```

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761742/is-it-possible-to-install-the-snap-application-in-an-offline-computer) suggested also downloading `ubuntu-core`

```
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# ls
docker_423.assert  docker_423.snap  ubuntu-core_1797.assert  ubuntu-core_1797.snap
```

After installing it, I get another error.

```
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# snap ack ubuntu-core_1797.assert
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# snap install ubuntu-core_1797.snap
2020-02-11T19:11:27-05:00 INFO Waiting for restart...
ubuntu-core 16-2 from Canonical✓ installed
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# snap ack docker_423.assert
root@docker:~/home/rabraham/tmp/snap# snap install docker_423.snap
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Ensure prerequisites for "docker" are available (cannot get nonce from store: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/nonces: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: No address associated with hostname)
```

Comment: @K7AAY. Thank you very much for your feedback. I have added the requested information. Let me know if more is required.