# Installing GNU Octave on an offline Ubuntu system

Tags: software-installation, octave

I want to install GNU octave on an offline Ubuntu 20.04 system. I have another Ubuntu 20.04 system which is connected to the Internet. Is there any way I can download all the dependencies, packages required for GNU octave and the source code together on the online system and then install on the offline system?

Comment: it is avaliable as a snap: https://snapcraft.io/octave

Comment: @Rinzwind I visited the link but it was not useful in downloading the snap package. The install button directs to the default Ubuntu Store app or the command `sudo snap install octave`. Anyway, I was able to do it with a bit of Google-Fu.

Comment: both answers will work. 1 is snap, the other through apt.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers (there can be only one) as correct by clicking on the gray check mark  next to that answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem as solved and help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For Snap Install

Snaps are confined, standalone Linux applications that bundle all their necessary dependencies, which means they do not need to rely on the underlying system, and can run independently of it.

The advantage of using Snap for installing an app like Octave in a computer that does not have Internet access is that everything self-contained. You just need to copy two files.

### On the Connected Computer

Open a terminal as the normal user by entering <kbd>Clrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command:

```
snap download octave
```

This will show the following output:

```
Fetching snap "octave"
Fetching assertions for "octave"
Install the snap with:
   snap ack octave_306.assert
   snap install octave_306.snap
```

Copy of move the two downloaded files, `octave_306.assert` and `octave_306.snap`, from the connected computer to a USB flash drive. The files are a little more than 300 MB in total. So, any USB flash drive will do.

### On the Unconnected Computer

Copy the two files from the USB drive to your home folder of the  **Unconnected computer**. "Your home folder" is the default folder when you open a terminal.

Open a terminal by entering <kbd>Clrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter these two lines, one at a time:

```
sudo snap ack ~/octave_306.assert
sudo snap install ~/octave_306.snap
```

After you type in the first line you will asked for your `sudo` password. After you enter the second line you will see this output:

```
octave 7.1.0 from GNU Octave (octave-snap✓) installed
```

**Now Octave is installed in the Unconnected Computer.**

You may delete the files `octave_306.assert` and `octave_306.snap` from your home folders after Octave is installed.

### Reference

[Is it possible to install the .snap application in an offline computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761742/is-it-possible-to-install-the-snap-application-in-an-offline-computer)

Note, on my Ubuntu 20.04 I **did not** need to install the package `ubuntu-core` as instructed in the above answer.

hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

The answer that you are looking for is given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469489/5649640 step-by-step:

First, execute this on the machine that has internet access to obtain all dependencies as *.deb files into the current directory.

```
apt-get download $(apt-rdepends octave|grep -v "^ " |grep -v "^libc-dev$")
```

Then, install the packages on the destination machine by navigating to the directory where the downloaded files have been copied into and perform this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```